# Difference between 第二回目　and 第二回

Tags: nuances

What is the difference between

> 第二回

and

> 第二回目

It seems to me that 第二回 is more common and 目　is superfluous.
Are there any cases where not adding 目　would sound strange? Whats the difference in feeling between with and without 目？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

第 and 目 serve the same function (第 being Chinese reading and 目 being Japanese). Using them both together is strange. That is not to say that nobody does it. In general, however, it is considered incorrect.

For official purposes 第 would be used. For example: 第23回関東中学校バレーボール大会, etc.

In conversational terms 目 would be used. Ex.: 今回のバレーボール大会は何回目ですか？

There is no real difference in feeling, but adding both might be seen as making it a bit less formal sounding or possibly for sake of clarity. Not too sure about the reasoning, though.

It is discussed (in Japanese) [here](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1111713416).